# jQuery how to select parent of element

Tags: jquery

I have this elements:

```
<div class="ELEMENT_LISTY" style="">

<div class="TITLE" id="174">string</div>
<div class="BUTTONY">
  <div class="POGLAD"></div>
  <div class="ZMIEN_NAZWE"></div>
  <div class="USUN"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

How to select element with class `.ELEMENT_LISTY` only when I have id `#174`?

Comment: `$('#174').closest('.ELEMENT_LISTY')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#174').parent()
```

would do it.

It should be noted that mumerical IDs can be tricky within browsers..you should consider using IDs that start with a letter.

Comment: To be specific, HTML5 allows `id` attributes starting with a number. Earlier versions of the spec didn't.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$('#174').parents('.ELEMENT_LISTY')....
```

Comment: Actually, .parent() should be sufficient.

Comment: @BarryChapman Could be risky, some browsers insert random DOM wrappers on certain objects - safer to specify where possible.

Comment: @BarryChapman Sure, if you know that the this is directly below the containing object.

Comment: The only problem with `.parents('.ELEMENT_LISTY')` is that it can pick up multiple parents if there are others with that class, safer to use `.closest('.ELEMENT_LISTY')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if ( $('div#174').length ) { //if element #174 exists
   $('div.ELEMENT_LISTY').whatever..
}
```